# using Google places api in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, google-places-api

I am creating a windows phone 8 app using Google places api. Using place search I can get the list of places. But when I am using Place Details search for different types, I have to create different C# classes for different types like bank, establishment etc. As there are so many types I can't create so many classes. So is there a solution to dynamically generate C# classes for every type?

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper seems to already exist.

I have NOT used it though

https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleMapsApi/

https://github.com/maximn/google-maps/wiki

Comment: It's a wrapper for Google Maps api, not for Google Places api.